# Yum install ffmpeg can't find repomd.xml

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, amazon-ec2, yum

I am trying to install ffmpeg on an EC2 instance, by doing the following:

(1) Editing: '/etc/yum.repos.d/dag.repo' and inserting:

'[dag]

name=Dag RPM Repository for Red Hat Enterprise Linux

baseurl=http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el$releasever/en/$basearch/dag

gpgcheck=1

enabled=1'

(2) Running 'yum update'

I get the error 'http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el8/en/i386/dag/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found'. Has anyone got an idea what the right URL is?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to use a EL repo with Fedora 8. Use the appropriate repo for the distro you're running.

Answer (score 0):

The .../el8/... part of your URL is wrong; the latest version of Red Hat Enterprise Linux is 5, so I'm guessing you need to replace .../el8/... with .../el5/...

This will depend on the version of Red Hat you're running on your EC2 instance, so check that before you edit the URL in your dag.repo file.